# Script which reacts to interrupt signal

Tags: scripting

How to make a script, which will write a string "signal caught" after sending 'interrupt signal' (after pressing ^C on the console, where the script was executed). On top of that after pressing third time CTRL-C it will ask user, if it should end (yes/no). If answer is "no" it will end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trap` in a script to intercept signals and perform some action such as incrementing a counter, displaying a message, etc.

See [Traps in bash guide for beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)